# converting Laravel array values into Javascript variables in blade

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a foreach in a blade that loops through an array as follows :

```
@foreach($qwin as $qwinners)

    <div>
     <a href="" >{{$qwinners->title}}</a> 

    </div>
    <br>
@endforeach
```

The above loop will result in 5 values.
I want to store each of the 5 values in 5 Javascript variables to be used after that in javascript functions. How can this conversion be done in a blade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign an array plucked from the collection to a Javascript object like so

```html
<script>
    var qwinnners = {!! $qwin->pluck('id', 'title') !!};
</script>
```

Hope this helps